# Adobe Air - Display banner through HTML

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm creating a desktop application with Adobe Flash CS 5 and AIR 2.5. Is it possible to display a banner through HTML and JavaScript inside the app?

JS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  var bsa = document.createElement('script');
     bsa.type = 'text/javascript';
     bsa.async = true;
     bsa.src = 'http://example.com/ac/bsa.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bsa);
})();
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="headerAd"> 
 <div id="bsap_124567" class="bsarocks bsap_1234524d29"></div>
  </div>
```

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use StageWebView

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html

Comment: Is it possible to load 2 websites into 2 different containers? I tried this code: **http://pastebin.com/9FKEdJyS** It gives me this error _Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=Load error._

Comment: That should be possible. Try adding ErrorEvent and IOErrorEvent handlers to the loaders to get more information. My guess is that you're using https rather than http in your URL's

Comment: import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;webView.addEventListener (IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, noXMLAvailable, false, 0, true);

Comment: private function noXMLAvailable (e:Event):void {
webView.removeEventListener (IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, noXMLAvailable);
trace(e);}

Comment: I'm using **http** and added the listener. Still getting the same error and no more information than this: **Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=Load error.** Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, just found the error. You can only load 1 stagewebview element at the time.